# What can cause a website to not always load

Tags: php, mysql, session, web, header

Roughly about 20% of the time when clicking on links in my website (www.slr-lens.co.uk), the site completely fails to load. I have tried removing and adding all code segments but to no avail... I've also asked the web hosts, but apparently the server is working normally.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what could cause a web page to sometimes not load? E.g. any specific lines in the php.ini? 
The site uses sessions, and there's quite a lot of mysql action for each page load.

Internet explorer will say:
"Internet Explorer can't load this page"
Google chrome will say:
This web page is not avialable: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
Firefox will sometimes only show a blank page.

Sorry for being so vague but its a really vague problem!
Thanks

Comment: If the server logs are of no use, you could try using the *net* panel in [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) to do some client-side tracing. It can help in some situations. Do you have any debug flags in the application that can be turned on to produce more useful logs?

Answer (score 2):

The answer (or at least a clue) likely lies within your PHP / Apache error logs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Apache logs or you just have a bad host. Either way, it seems to load every time here (10+). Have you tried replicating this problem somewhere else?

Comment: Well there's nothing useful in the error_log, you're right, I could try replicating the site on another web host to see if the same problem occurs, that might be the way forward....

Comment: The problem is also more prevalent when using chrome, which makes things more confusing...

Comment: The joys of flakey DNS prefetching. If it does that on other websites you can turn it off (Chrome -> Preferences -> Under the Hood -> Use DNS Prefetching to...)

Comment: Try it from another physical location also, it may be your ISPs fault